# Convert a UTC Timestamp to a datetime object, taking daylight savings time into account

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

Using:

```
 time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("UTC")).timetuple())
```

The timestamp on April 19. 2012 shortly after 10:00 in New York was 1334840917. Given this timestamp, how can I convert it back to a datetime object that takes daylight savings time into account?

If I do:

```
   >>>eastern = pytz.timezone("Us/Eastern")
   >>>dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1334840917,eastern)
   >>>dt.hour
```

The output is: 9

Comment: Is there a reason why your timestamps are in local time, not UTC?

Comment: The timestamps are in UTC, is that not what: time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("UTC")).timetuple())
does?

Comment: Yep, you are right it does. I've been using `calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime.utcnow().utctimetuple())` which should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

`dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1334840917 + time.daylight*3600)`

Comment: I think time.daylight uses the local time to determine if it's daylight savings time. However if I have timestamps from prior to March 11, 2012 I don't think this will work.

Comment: Yes, i didn't think you want get time from another source. You can't use just plain timestamps to get information about daylight saving, AFAIK.